# Trying To Run ExifTool From AppleScript In Automator

Tags: applescript, automator

I have a small AppleScript setup in Automator which does the following.

**Prompts user to select a json file
Prompts user to select a folder**

It is then supposed to **execute Exiftool** located in /usr/local/bin but it never runs it.

here is the AppleScript code I have in Automator

```
--Select JSON File
set theFile to choose file
set theFile to POSIX path of theFile


--Select Folder
set theFolderPath to choose folder
set theFolderPath to POSIX path of theFolderPath

-- Run ExifTool
set exiftool to "/usr/local/bin/exiftool -json=" & theFile & " " & theFolderPath


-- Display Dialog to see the full command.
--When I paste the contents into terminal it works !
display dialog exiftool

-- Run ExifTool
do shell script exiftool
```

The screenshot below is what I get from displaying the dialog with the full command. If I paste this into Terminal it works but not from within Automator.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong please.

[image]

Comment: have a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-TNTAG1-MY_COMMAND_WORKS_FINE_IN_TERMINAL__BUT_WHEN_I_TRY_TO_USE_IT_IN_DO_SHELL_SCRIPT__I_GET_AN_ERROR_ABOUT____COMMAND_NOT_FOUND______WHAT___S_GOING_ON_) on how to use _do shell script_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you are using **Automator** when your code can be run from **Script Editor**.

Honestly, I know nothing about the `exiftool` but I was thinking that maybe this following AppleScript gets the exif data you are looking for?

```
activate
set jsonFile to quoted form of POSIX path of ¬
    (choose file of type "public.json" with prompt "Select a .json file.")

set exiftoolInfoBasic to do shell script "cat " & jsonFile & ¬
    " |/usr/local/bin/exiftool - |grep -E '^ExifTool|^File|^MIME'"

set exiftoolInfoFull to do shell script "cat " & ¬
    jsonFile & " |/usr/local/bin/exiftool -"
```

Comment: Thank you, That way is much cleaner and works very well

Comment: thank you, will certainly check that out